# TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation - Insert blob into database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, html2canvas

I have this javascript code which is supposed to create a screenshot of the `image-container` div and send it to a new php script:

```
html2canvas(image-container).then(function (canvas) {
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"//domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {action: "addblobtodb", image: blob},
            success: function(id) {
                console.log("Succesfully inserted into DB: " + id);
            }
        });
```

The php code that is called in the `admin-ajax.php` file is shown below. It tries to insert the image blob in the `test_images` table, which I created myself. It is asimple MySql table with an ID and image_data:

```
function add_poster_to_db() {
    global $wpdb;
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    ob_start();

    // Insert een nieuwe rij aan de test_poster_images db
    $wpdb->insert('test_images', array(
        'image_data' => $image,
    ));
    $db_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    wp_send_json( $db_id );

    die();
}
```

When calling this javascript code, the following errors are shown:
[image: error]

How can I insert the blob in the Wordpress table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you meant to be passing a **blob-URL** for the image instead of just blob-data?

Because it doesn't look like you're converting the blob to a URL with this...

```
canvas.toBlob(function (blob){

  jQuery.ajax({

    url:"//domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {action: "addblobtodb", image: blob},
    success: function(id) {console.log("Succesfully inserted into DB: " + id);

   }

});
```

So I would try this...

```
canvas.toBlob((blob)=>{

 let Url=URL.createObjectURL(blob);

   jQuery.ajax({

    url:"//domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

    type: "POST",

    data: {action: "addblobtodb", image: Url},    // <-- Image blob url passed here

    success: function(id) {console.log("Succesfully inserted into DB: " + id);}

   });

 },'image/png',1); // <--- specify the type & quality of image here
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried your code, but this only save the generated url in the database. So it generates a url (f.e. https://example.com/4d594f29-c227-4f76-a8f6-c6d68c046593) and inserts it like that in the DB table. Afterwards, I am not able to access the generated url. How can I save the image in the database in a way that I can have a look at it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

OK then, let the DB have the blob in raw format...

```
canvas.toBlob((blob)=>{

   jQuery.ajax({

    url:"//domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

    type: "POST",

    data: {action: "addblobtodb", image: blob},

    success: function(id) {console.log("Succesfully inserted into DB: " + id);}

   });

 },'image/png',1); // <--- specify the type & quality of image here
```